# Issue with Garbage Collection

Tags: java

I have code some what like

```
class HappyGarbage01 
{ 
   public static void main(String args[]) 
   {
       HappyGarbage01 h = new HappyGarbage01(); 
       h.methodA(); /* Line 6 */
   } 
   Object methodA() 
   {
       Object obj1 = new Object(); 
       Object [] obj2 = new Object[1]; 
       obj2[0] = obj1; 
       obj1 = null; 
       return obj2[0]; 
   } 
}
```

Will the most chance of the garbage collector being invoked be after line 9 or 10?

Comment: When the GC runs won't make any difference to the object returned, but the GC is highly unlikely to trigger.

Comment: What is the issue with garbage collection? You don't know when the GC will invoke.

Comment: Can you label lines 9 and 10 as well as clarify your question? I don't see what you want us to help you with.

Comment: You say you have an "issue" with garbage collection. What is your issue? What is it that you really want to know about the GC?

Comment: I agree with @ChristopherSchneider, we don't know whether it is going to be invoked or not. But if you are asking whether it is eligible to be gc or not, then that is another case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Garbage collection algorithms, most of them mark-and-sweep (in Java anyway most are mark/sweep), take far more time than just a single instruction or a few instructions, so you cannot narrow them down to one or two lines of code.

Secondly, they run in the background, usually (but not always) on separate threads, so they are not started at a specific instruction in your code.

Thirdly, they only run when your overall memory consumption justifies that they run.  They never run because of a few bytes here and there.  The default heap size is something like 256 mb, so a few bytes like in your sample code are literally nothing of consequence and have no effect.

Fourthly, they run only based on memory consumption, not the reachability of objects, there is no way for a garbage collector to know before-hand how much memory can be collected, only after they start will they detect that one of your objects is no longer reachable.

For all of these reasons, your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

Garbage Collector probably won't ever be run for this program because the program doesn't live long enough.

Answer (score 1):

Basic solution for your question is to put:

```
System.gc();
```

or

```
Runtime.gc();
```

in place, where you would like to call garbage collector, but you can't be sure, that the garbage collector will be forced to work.

Other, but more complecated solution is to use WeakReference objects.
For more, you can read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector won't be invoked after line 9 because the reference to `obj1` is stored in `obj2[0]`. The Object `obj1` still exists on the heap and can be accessed by an active thread through the reference stored in `obj2[0]`.

Rather the garbage collection takes place after line 6. Garbage collection takes place after the method has returned its reference to the object. The method returns to line 6, there is no reference to store the return value. So the answer should be after line 6.

Comment: It could run after line 6. But you can't say that it _will_.

Comment: Right. The more preferable word would be it "could".

Comment: The question and the answer is not relevant, he is asking whether the gc will be invoked or not.

Comment: @HendrikT Actually I wanted an answer of that sort like what jiltedpotato said. Perhaps I need to edit the question. Could you help me with that so that I could get off the negative votes off my question? I don't want my question to be _not_ useful.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector runs whenever the JVM decides it should run. In this program, it will probably never run because the program is too short. However, in larger programs, it would typically run when the program starts using a lot of memory.

---

The garbage collector frees up memory used by objects that can never be referenced. In this case, you create an object and an array.

You have a reference to the object throughout all of methodA, either in obj1 or obj2[0]. Then, you return a reference to it, but the reference is forgotten. Therefore, the object can only be collected after methodA returns. Note that if you stored a reference to it in the main function, it would never be garbage collected since you could always reference it later in the main function. When the program exits, the operating system would clean it up when it frees the memory used by the JVM.

You only keep a reference to the array inside the function. Therefore, when the function ends, the array will be GC-able.